# Nuxt 3 & Strapi 4.12 - SFC (script setup) - Update useState inside function using `this` is undefined in build

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs3, vue-sfc, nuxt-strapi

### Environment

`"@strapi/strapi": "4.12.0",`

`"nuxt": "^3.6.5",`

### Current situation

In my development environment, I have a projects page with a category filter that can show either all projects or a category with the corresponding projects.

I am using `useAsyncQuery` to fetch the projects and categories from Strapi.

In the filter there is a dropdown with various categories. On click of those categories, the function `switchCategory(filter.id)` is called. In that function are various states updated using `this` .

See here the `script setup`:

```
<script setup>
import { projectsQuery } from "~/queries/projects/archive";
import { filterQuery } from "~/queries/projects/filter";

const { data: filterRes } = await useAsyncQuery(filterQuery)
const { data: projectsRes } = await useAsyncQuery(projectsQuery)

var isLoading = useState('isLoading', () => false)
var filterActive = useState('filterActive', () => false)

var filterActiveText = useState('filterActiveText', () => 'Alle projecten')
const projectsUrl = useState('projectsUrl', () => '/projecten/')

const filters = useState('filters', () => filterRes.value.projectCategories.data)
const projects = useState('projects', () => projectsRes.value.projects.data)
var filteredProjects = useState('filteredProjects', () => projects)

function switchCategory(id) {

  this.isLoading = true
  this.filterActive = false;

  document.getElementById("projects-container").scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });


  setTimeout(() => {
    if (id) {
      this.filters.map((item) => {
        if (id == item.id) {
          this.filteredProjects = item.attributes.projects.data;
          this.filterActiveText = item.attributes.Title;
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.filteredProjects = this.projects;
      this.filterActiveText = 'Alle projecten';
    }
    this.isLoading = false;
  }, 600)
}
```

And in the `template` element

```
<div class="flex flex-col gap-y-8 md:gap-y-24 lg:gap-y-40 transition-all duration-600 ease-in-out" :class="{
  'blur-0': !isLoading,
  'blur': isLoading,
}">
  <div class="grid md:grid-cols-2 gap-8 md:gap-16 lg:gap-24 relative" v-for="(project, id) in filteredProjects" :key="id">
    <Nuxt-Link class="absolute inset-0 w-full h-full z-10"
      :to="projectsUrl + project.attributes.Slug"></Nuxt-Link>
    <div class="flex flex-col items-start justify-between">
      <div class="sticky top-40 pb-16 lg:pb-20 prose-xl">
        <h3 class="text-xl md:text-4xl lg:text-5xl font-bold">{{ project.attributes.Title }}</h3>
        <p class="block">{{ project.attributes.Intro }}</p>
      </div>
      <Button class="flex mb-4" color="light" :to="projectsUrl + project.attributes.Slug">
        Project bekijken
      </Button>
    </div>
    <div class="-order-1 md:order-1 relative">
      <div class="aspect-video md:aspect-square lg:aspect-[12/18] relative">
        <Media
          :url="project.attributes.FeaturedImage.data.attributes.url"
          :extension="project.attributes.FeaturedImage.data.attributes.ext"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

### Problem

When I build the project, using `nuxt build` and then start a node server using `node .output/server/index.mjs` the projects get loaded in fine. But when I try to filter, trying to update the variables like `isLoading` and `filterActive` inside the `switchCategory` function, it throws me: `TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'isLoading')`.

**Fix attempt #1**

I thought, maybe when it's built, it doesn't understand the `this` context (because `this` is also undefined when I try to `console.log` it). So I tried to refactor the code like this:

```
const switchCategory = (id) => {

  isLoading = true
  filterActive = false;

  document.getElementById("projects-container").scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });


  setTimeout(() => {
    if (id && filters) {
      filters && filters.value.map((item) => {
        if (id == item.id) {
          filteredProjects = item.attributes.projects.data;
          filterActiveText = item.attributes.Title;
        }
      });
    } else {
      filteredProjects = projects;
      filterActiveText = 'Alle projecten';
    }
    isLoading = false;
  }, 600)
}
```

I changed the normal function to an arrow function and removed the `this.`
In the setTimeout I had to change the `filters.map` to `filters.value.map` (not entirely sure why it changed format).

Code runs normal now (without errors), but it doesn't change update the DOM of the projects loop in the template.

**Fix attempt #2**

After searching and debugging for a pretty long time, I found in the Vue docs about [`defineExpose`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose).
It mentions that `script setup` is *"closed by default"*. I (desperately) added it to my script setup with all variables:

```
defineExpose({
  filterRes,
  projectsRes,
  pageRes,
  isLoading,
  filterActive,
  filterActiveText,
  projectsUrl,
  filters,
  projects,
  filteredProjects,
})
```

Unfortunately, and as expected, it didn't magically work.

------

### Solution?

I am most likely looking at this in the wrong way, but I can't think of any other way on how to fix this.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think i can supply a straight working code snippet, but perhaps can guide you into a solution?

useState is only available in build time, or well, component render. So changing the query after render doesnt make it update. Perhaps re-render the component after state mutation?

Comment: Thanks for commenting! So I've dived into trying to accomplish to rerender the component. It kinda "worked" when trying to filter for the first time, but after that it didn't work anymore. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I think I (finally) fixed the problem.

So after trying sven folkerts guidance to a solution (thanks btw), using [this article](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render) as one of the references *and* sleeping one night before continuing, I've went at this in a different direction.

I continued with the arrow function approach in **Fix attempt #1**.

I researched more about [`refreshNuxtData`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/refresh-nuxt-data) but didn't have much luck.

Then I went into into using `ref` instead of `useState`. That worked.
Both in development and build.

See my final code here:

```
<script setup>
import { pagesQuery } from "~/apollo/queries/pages";
import { projectsQuery } from "~/apollo/queries/projects/archive";
import { filterQuery } from "~/apollo/queries/projects/filter";


const { data: filterRes } = await useAsyncQuery(filterQuery)
const { data: projectsRes } = await useAsyncQuery(projectsQuery)
const { data: pageRes } = await useAsyncQuery(pagesQuery, {
  slug: 'projecten'
});

var isLoading = ref(false)
var filterActive = ref(false)
var filterActiveText = ref('Alle projecten')

const projectsUrl = '/projecten/'
const filters = filterRes.value.projectCategories.data
const projects = projectsRes.value.projects.data
var filteredProjects = ref(projects)

const switchCategory = (id) => {

  isLoading.value = true
  filterActive.value = false;

  document.getElementById("projects-container").scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (id) {
      filters && filters.map((item) => {
        if (id == item.id) {
          filteredProjects.value = item.attributes.projects.data;
          filterActiveText.value = item.attributes.Title;
        }
      });
    } else {
      filteredProjects.value = projects;
      filterActiveText.value = 'Alle projecten';
    }
    isLoading.value = false;
  }, 600)
}
```

As you can see I changed all `useState` variables to `ref` (and changed all illogical `useState` declarations to normal declarations).

In my `switchCategory` function I only had to update all variable updates to update the `value` of the `ref` to `var.value`.

I'm happy it's working now, but I am still unsure if this is the ideal / most logical way.